# ¿como crear apliacación Xamarin Forms con Sqlite net standard?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

tengo visual studio 2017 estoy intentando crear una aplicacion en xamarin forms, que almacena datos en una base de datos sqlite.
todos los ejemplos que encuentro son utilizando sqlite.net-pcl, la cual ya no es compatible con las nuevas librerías netStandard 2.0
alguien tiene algun ejemplo, o sabe que librerias de sqlite puedo descargar de nuget para crear una aplicacion compatible con NetStandard 2.0
muchas gracias.

Comment: Te recomiendo revises [ask], el formato de tu pregunta no es correcto en el sitio, me parece que lo que deseas es solo una opinión.

Comment: no es una opinión, quiero saber como crear un proyecto con Sqlite utililzando librerias NetStandar 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa la versión [-pre](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/1.5.166-beta) de [sqlite-net-pcl](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) (ojo que no es la misma que sqlite.net-pcl). Acá estamos usando la versión 1.5.166-beta en una app y funciona sin problemas.

Comment: muchas gracias, con esta versión si que parece que funciona bien.